# Problems with ILMerge

Tags: c#, dll, ilmerge

I am trying to put .dll fles in my .exe file and I am getting this error:

```
    ILMerge.exe: The assembly 'Final' has a value for it's PeKind flag 
    'Ilonly, requires32bits' that is not compatible with 'Ilonly, requires 32 
    bits, prefers32bits'
```

I entered this command in the command line:

```
   ILMerge.exe exe\ConsoleApplication1.exe lib\Final.dll /out:Final.exe /closed /zeroPeKind
```

Could anyone help me on this? I am not sure what this means, thank you!

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

(1) A possible work-around, use `CorFlags` to change your library to match the required value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool

(2) Your console application seems to have been built with "prefer 32 bit" in project properties.

You can clear this option, build your console application and try ILMerge again
[image: Prefer 32 bit]